# Java Robot Class KeyPress

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

The code

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

does not close after printing the `V`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to release the keys after pressing them:

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Comment: You might as well write a method that presses and releases a key. :-)